# android HEX color not working on some devicec

Tags: android, colors, hex

I have this color in values/color

```
`<color name="custom_green">#09c09b</color>`
```

and use it in my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/custom_green">

</RelativeLayout>
```

it works fine in nexus 5,4, samsung galaxy s4 ..., but not works on some devices, for example sony xperia or samsung galaxy duos 2(don't show anything or show black).

On nexus 5
[image]

on sony xperia

[image]

Comment: do you have different layouts for different screen densities

Comment: no i have one layout for all

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I don't know why it's happening but i found a working solution for me.
Try to add `FF` before your color value, it will tell android that you don't want to have any transparency with your color.

So your `colors.xml` will look like:

```
<color name="custom_green">#FF09C09B</color>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for comment , but not helped.